# Error whle installing Hadoop on windows

Tags: xml, windows, hadoop

I'm following these instructions:
http://www.ics.uci.edu/~shantas/Install_Hadoop-2.6.0_on_Windows10.pdf

Completed them exactly (used the exact written versions and not newer versions)
Trying to install hadoop 2.6.5.

This is how I configured the hdfs-site.xml:

hdfs-site.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<!--
 Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 You may obtain a copy of the License at
 http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 limitations under the License. See accompanying LICENSE file.
-->
<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->
<configuration>
<property><name>dfs.replication</name><value>1</value></property>
<property> <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name><value>/hadoop-
2.6.5/data/name</value><final>true</final></property>
<property><name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name><value>/hadoop-
2.6.5/data/data</value><final>true</final> </property>
</configuration>
```

And when I try to run hadoop namenode -format 
I get this error on the command line:

```
17/11/28 23:51:24 INFO http.HttpServer2: addJerseyResourcePackage: packageName=org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.web.resources;org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.resources, pathSpec=/webhdfs/v1/*
17/11/28 23:51:24 INFO http.HttpServer2: Jetty bound to port 50070
17/11/28 23:51:24 INFO mortbay.log: jetty-6.1.26
17/11/28 23:51:24 INFO mortbay.log: Started HttpServer2$SelectChannelConnectorWithSafeStartup@0.0.0.0:50070
17/11/28 23:51:24 ERROR common.Util: Syntax error in URI /hadoop-
2.6.5/data/name. Please check hdfs configuration.
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 8: /hadoop-
2.6.5/data/name
        at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2848)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3021)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3105)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3063)
        at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:588)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Util.stringAsURI(Util.java:48)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Util.stringCollectionAsURIs(Util.java:98)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getStorageDirs(FSNamesystem.java:1435)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getNamespaceDirs(FSNamesystem.java:1390)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkConfiguration(FSNamesystem.java:675)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFromDisk(FSNamesystem.java:729)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.loadNamesystem(NameNode.java:539)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:598)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:765)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:749)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1446)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1512)
17/11/28 23:51:24 WARN common.Util: Path /hadoop-
2.6.5/data/name should be specified as a URI in configuration files. Please update hdfs configuration.
17/11/28 23:51:24 ERROR common.Util: Error while processing URI: /hadoop-
2.6.5/data/name
java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
```

More errors...

```
    java.io.IOException: No image directories available!
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.saveFSImageInAllDirs(FSImage.java:1099)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.saveFSImageInAllDirs(FSImage.java:1091)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.format(FSImage.java:150)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.format(NameNode.java:945)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1387)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1512)
17/11/29 00:23:23 FATAL namenode.NameNode: Failed to start namenode.
java.io.IOException: No image directories available!
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.saveFSImageInAllDirs(FSImage.java:1099)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.saveFSImageInAllDirs(FSImage.java:1091)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.format(FSImage.java:150)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.format(NameNode.java:945)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1387)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1512)
17/11/29 00:23:23 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
17/11/29 00:23:23 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at yonatan/192.168.1.24
************************************************************/
```

Any idea?

BTW: hadoop version seems to be fine:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>hadoop version
Hadoop 2.6.5
Subversion https://github.com/apache/hadoop.git -r e8c9fe0b4c252caf2ebf1464220599650f119997
Compiled by sjlee on 2016-10-02T23:43Z
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
From source with checksum f05c9fa095a395faa9db9f7ba5d754
This command was run using /D:/hadoop-2.6.5/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.6.5.jar

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Edit: 
After editing the XML like @cricket_007 suggested, the hadoop namenode -f worked, but when trying to run as administrator start-dfs i'm receiving these errors:

```
    17/11/29 21:10:36 INFO ipc.Server: Starting Socket Reader #1 for port 50020
17/11/29 21:10:36 INFO datanode.DataNode: Opened IPC server at /0.0.0.0:50020
17/11/29 21:10:36 INFO datanode.DataNode: Refresh request received for nameservices: null
17/11/29 21:10:36 INFO datanode.DataNode: Starting BPOfferServices for nameservices: <default>
17/11/29 21:10:36 WARN common.Util: Path /hadoop-2.6.5/data/data should be specified as a URI in configuration files. Please update hdfs configuration.
17/11/29 21:10:36 INFO datanode.DataNode: Block pool <registering> (Datanode Uuid unassigned) service to localhost/127.0.0.1:50071 starting to offer service
17/11/29 21:10:36 INFO ipc.Server: IPC Server listener on 50020: starting
17/11/29 21:10:36 INFO ipc.Server: IPC Server Responder: starting
17/11/29 21:10:38 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:50071. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
17/11/29 21:10:40 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:50071. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
```

Last edit:Found the problem. Needed to define the D drive for the hadoop location

```
    <value>/D:/hadoop-2.6.5/data/name</value>
    <final>true</final>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
    <value>/D:/hadoop-2.6.5/data/data</value>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Illegal character in path at index 8:

Looks like you have line breaks. Remove them from the XML, or at least format it properly.

```
<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
    <value>/hadoop-2.6.5/data/name</value>
    <final>true</final>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
    <value>/hadoop-2.6.5/data/data</value>
    <final>true</final>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

I've typically seen the hard drive mentioned in the path. `D:\\hadoop\data`, for example. Otherwise, I think it defaults to the C drive

I would also strongly suggest against placing the HDFS data in the same location as the extracted Hadoop tarball. In a real Hadoop environment, the namenode and datanode data should be on completely separate disks. Hard drives are ticking time bombs.

Comment: Ok i'll try it out later. About the drives : I have 500 GB overall, I have the Windows at C, and Hadoop at D (~250 GB each) (Created D right now for hadoop). How do you suggest me to divide the drives? Should I create new Volume or something ?

Comment: Partitions are still part of a single physical hard drive. You would need to physically buy a new hard drive and create a volume on it. Again, this is for a production grade environment, not necessarily for testing a local Hadoop instance (Worth mentioning that running a Linux Virtual machine would make installation much easier / repeatable)

Comment: Oh ok I get it, it's for university project not a production one. Thanks.

Comment: cricket_007 I added the result of what you told me: 
namenode -f worked but still get17/11/29 21:10:38 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:50071. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)ting these errors when running start-dfs
 
It tries to connect without succeeding

Comment: You probably want 1) Password-less SSH to your own machine. https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html#Setup_passphraseless_ssh 2) Use the FQDN rather than `localhost` (this isn't critical, but might help) https://serverfault.com/a/73634/328634